# How to filter on a primeNG table with a dropdown and apply the filter only when pressing the apply button?

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am trying to filter a column in the primeNG table with a drop down menu, but I want to apply the filter only when I press the Apply button. Now filtering happens in the onChange event. If I remove the onChange event the filter does not work

This is the code without onChange event:

```
<p-table #dt1 [value]="customers">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>
               <div>
              Status
              <p-columnFilter field="status" matchMode="equals" display="menu"   [showOperator]="false" [showMatchModes]="false"> 
                  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
                      <p-dropdown [ngModel]="value" [options]="statuses"  placeholder="Any">
                          <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
                              {{option.label}}
                          </ng-template>
                      </p-dropdown>
                  </ng-template>
              </p-columnFilter>
          </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-customer>
        <tr>        
            <td>
            {{customer.status}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

When I press the Apply button the filter value is null

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo-hbvzhe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you still need the answer, but I'll post it anyway for other people to find it.

The documentation isn't really clear on the **filterCallback** element of the filter (feel free to tell me if i have missed something), but i managed to stop it from calling the lazy load with this code:

On the filter template itself:

```
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
    <p-dropdown
      [ngModel]="value"
      (onChange)="customFilterCallback(filter, $event.value)"></p-dropdown>
  </ng-template>

 customFilterCallback(filter: (a) => void, value: any): void {
   this.stopListening = true;
   filter(value);
   this.stopListening = false;
 }
```

On the method listening to the onLazyLoad event of the table:

```
(onLazyLoad)="lazy_load($event)"

lazy_load(event: LazyLoadEvent): void {
  if (this.stopListening) {
    return;
  }
  ...loading stuff
}
```

Using this solution you can stop the loading every time you change the custom filter.
Of course, the data displayed isn't going to match the filter until the "Apply" button is pressed (or until the lazy loading is triggered any other way).

It really would be better if the library provided a way to stop the onLazyLoad event when the filter is changed.

EDIT:
This of course only works for custom filters, when you add a new constraint to the default filter, it's going to trigger the lazy loading.

Comment: Hi @khai, thanks for your help. This is what I was looking for. Is there a way to apply all the filters locally in the lazy_load event? Here an edited stackblitz with your suggestion https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo-w7mtx7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: There is probably a way to do it by editing the table "filters" property manually, but i don't know if the interface is going to update with it. I wouldn't trust it

Comment: @khai, thanks!  this helped just by being able to debug the filter code.

Answer (score 9):

I have found another way by overriding the `Apply` and `Clear` buttons. My example relates to the selection of calendar dates, but the point is the same.
The filter template looks as follows:

```
<p-columnFilter field="createdDate" matchMode="between" [display]="'menu'" [showAddButton]="false"
    [showMatchModes]="false" [showOperator]="false" [showClearButton]="false" [showApplyButton]="false">
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
        <p-calendar #createdCalendar [inline]="true" [readonlyInput]="true" [selectionMode]="'range'"></p-calendar>
        <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between p-ai-center p-mt-3">
            <p-button label="Clear" styleClass="p-button-outlined" (onClick)="filter(undefined)"></p-button>
            <p-button label="Apply" (onClick)="filter(createdCalendar.value)"></p-button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-columnFilter>
```

Comment: this deserve to be the accepted answer, a lot cleaner and very well done !